# How to add the tag name in the post title?

Tags: seo, blogger

consider question asked by the person in stackoverflow is like

> Preferred/idiomatic way to insert into a map

When i search the above question in google, it shows the results like

> c++ - Preferred/idiomatic way to insert into a map - Stack Overflow

How tag of the question is added in front of the question. 
How to achieve the same in my blogging posts?

Note:
I am using Google's blogger.

Comment: StackExchange has programmed this functionality into their software.   They are not using an off-the-shelf solution for their website.  They have built it custom.   They have complete control over how the site works.   You would have to get Google to build the same functionality into blogger.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much easy to achieve:

There is a title for the question in stackoverflow / you would have a title for the blog as well.

Then there are tags per question in stackoverflow, similar way you can have tagging enabled for your blog as well, where people tag the category to which their blog post belong. Example : travel, health, leisure etc

Then while generating page for that blog, you can set the `<title>` in html to be:

`<Set of tags searated by , > - title of the blog`, with proper validations at backend like:

**Add tag only if available**:

You should not restrict your user to tag a blog to category, you can ask them to tag by informing them, that this increases their blog's reach. Based on available or not your backend should set the tags in title rather than breaking it.

**Restrict tags in title to a limit** 
For this you can have a priority attached to tags, like travel might have a priority 10 while leisure can have 2 and if you want to have only one tag in title and user has selected 2 tags (both travel and leisure), then your backend can select travel and append to title based on priority of tags.

Comment: Could you know how to change in the google blogger code